# What Debian packages are there that depend on a service while building?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, package-management, deb

I have an issue trying to build a package which depends on several other packages, some of which include a service. Said service tries to start in the postinst script and as a result fails the build because within the build environment, `systemd` is not installed.

I would like to see some official packages that have a similar issue. At this point, I do not need the service of the dependency to be running, but the postinst script still needs to work (obviously?!) and in this case, it attempts to start the service manually because the name doesn't match the package name (also, there are actually 2 services in that one package, but I digress).

My script as it stands attempts to do:

```
systemctl enable ipload
systemctl start ipload
```

which works just fine when installing the package on any Ubuntu system, but fails in the build of the system that depends on its `-dev` package.

My question is:

What are existing official Debian packages that have a similar issue: depend on other packages which normally start a service and are required in a build?

That way I can make my own package work in a similar way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `dh_installsystemd` in your package construction to set up your services; this will generate appropriately robust snippets in your maintainer scripts. See for example [`g810-led`’s `debian/rules`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/g810-led/-/blob/master/debian/rules); this shows how to handle units which don’t match the package’s name:

```
dh_installsystemd --no-stop-on-upgrade --no-start --name=g810-led-reboot
```

(You shouldn’t use `--no-stop-on-upgrade` or `--no-start`.)

The resulting `postinst` contains

```bash
# Automatically added by dh_installsystemd/13.3.4
if [ "$1" = "configure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-upgrade" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-deconfigure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-remove" ] ; then
        # This will only remove masks created by d-s-h on package removal.
        deb-systemd-helper unmask 'g810-led-reboot.service' >/dev/null || true

        # was-enabled defaults to true, so new installations run enable.
        if deb-systemd-helper --quiet was-enabled 'g810-led-reboot.service'; then
                # Enables the unit on first installation, creates new
                # symlinks on upgrades if the unit file has changed.
                deb-systemd-helper enable 'g810-led-reboot.service' >/dev/null || true
        else
                # Update the statefile to add new symlinks (if any), which need to be
                # cleaned up on purge. Also remove old symlinks.
                deb-systemd-helper update-state 'g810-led-reboot.service' >/dev/null || true
        fi
fi
# End automatically added section
```

This uses `deb-systemd-helper` which handles installation with or without `systemd`.

You’ll also see a corresponding `prerm` and `postrm`.

It is however unusual (but not unheard of) for a `-dev` package to end up depending on packages shipping services; you might want to split things up further (for example a `-dev` package, a library package, and a package containing the services).

Comment: This is a good point. I could have a separate library package and then the tool & service don't get installed (since the build doesn't require those, at least in this case). Also it is certainly good practice to make use of the debhelpers whenever possible.

Comment: One important factor, so that override is taken in account, is to use debian/compat if 12 or more. At first I had 10 and it did nothing...

Answer (score 0):

I had difficulties to get the [dh_installsystemd](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/dh_installsystemd.1.en.html) to work, so I wanted to have my own answer about the various steps I took to get it perfect (nearly¹).

1. Make it verbose

   The trace of the functionality when things work can be pretty light unless you turn on the verbosity. This is done by adding the following to the `debian/rules` file:

   ```
   export DH_VERBOSE=1
   ```

   Delete or comment out once done debugging.
2. Place file under `debian/...`

   In my original, the file was defined as `contrib/ipload.service`. I was installing the file *by hand* (using the `iplock.install` file) and then using the `systemctl` commands to setup the service².

   For this to work with the debhelpers offered by systemd, you want to move the file to `debian/...` like so:

   ```
   git mv contrib/ipload.service debian/iplock.ipload.service
   ```

   Notice how the name changes. It is now three parts:

   - `iplock` -- the name of the package where we want to add the service
   - `ipload` -- the name of the service file (as before)
   - `service` -- the type of systemd file, a service
3. Make sure the compatibility level is correct

   There are now two ways to define the compatibility level. The old way, which is to have a `debian/compat` file. That file simply includes a level (i.e. a test file with a decimal number such as 12).

   The new way is to create a `debhelper-compat` dependency in your `debian/control` file.

   ```
   Build-Depends: debhelper-compat (= 12), ...
   ```

   Either way, make sure that it is at least 12 otherwise the override of the systemd debhelpers **does not** kick in at all (they will be ignored). If you created your package a while back, it is not unlikely still using a smaller compatibility level.
4. Actually Install the Service Files

   Contrary to many projects, this one has two `.service` files. One which is called `ipwall.service` and goes in the `ipwall` package. Another, as mentioned above, which is named `ipload.service` and has to go in the `iplock` package and that second one fails because of the name mismatch.

   As mentioned above, I first had to rename the file properly (`<package name>.<service name>.<extension>`). Then I had to have an override like so:

   ```
   override_dh_installsystemd:
       dh_installsystemd
       dh_installsystemd --name=ipload
   ```

   The first call to `dh_installsystemd` installs the `ipwall` properly (all the defaults, as usual, really). The second call specifies a name (`ipload`) and that's what gets installed... where you might ask?! That is defined by the filename as mentioned above: `iplock.ipload.service`, so it will be installed inside `iplock`.

---

¹ I say *nearly* because I still have an issue because the user gets created, then the service starts, then the settings are updated. So the very first run use the default settings without the changes made by the administrator. One issue at a time, I guess.

² And that was what I had issues with earlier because systemd doesn't get installed on the build system. Note that the scripts actually test whether `/run/systemd/system` is a directory before using any systemd tools.

```
if [ -d /run/systemd/system ]
then
    ...here you can use systemctl...
fi
```